# How do I display a second array inside my computed property in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, computed-properties

I want to display a second array inside my computed property, but only if a checkbox is checked. Otherwise the first list should only display.

I've managed to get my fist list to work with my code and it displays as it should, I've also got a method that makes the list sort alfabetically (that is what I refer to as categories).

How do I merge in the other array if my checkbox value is true?

Here's some code

```
data: function() {
   return {
     checked: false,
     fruitList: [ //Fist list
       "Apple",
       "Grapes",
       "Mango",
       "Oranges",
       "Banana",
       "Dragon fruit",
       "Pinapple",
       "Coconut",
       "Strawberry"
     ],
      vegetableList:[ //Second list, should only display if checkbox is true
      "cucumber",
       "tomato",
       "onion"
       ]
    };
},
methods:{
return{
 sorted(list) {
     return list.sort();
   }
}
},
computed: {
   categorizedWords() {
     let map = {};
      this.fruitList.forEach(word => {
       let key = word.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
       let list = map[key];
       if (list === undefined) {
         list = [];
         map[key] = this.sortedList(list);
       }
       list.push(word);
     });

     var sortedCategories = this.sortedList(Object.keys(map));
     var sortedMap = sortedCategories.map(category => {
       return { category: category, word: map[category] };
     });
     return sortedMap;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, so I had it allmost and I've figured it all out now. 
 So I changed my code to this and it worked, this is inside my computed property:

```
 computed: {
   categorizedWords() {
     let map = {};
     let isCheched = this.checked;

      let allGreens = this.fruitList;

      if (isChecked === true) {
        allGreens = allGreens.concat(this.vegetableList);
      }

      allGreens.forEach(word => {
       let key = word.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
       let list = map[key];
       if (list === undefined) {
         list = [];
         map[key] = this.sortedList(list);
       }
       list.push(word);
     });

     var sortedCategories = this.sortedList(Object.keys(map));
     var sortedMap = sortedCategories.map(category => {
       return { category: category, word: map[category] };
     });
     return sortedMap;
   }
 }
```